# Can I add more than one phone number as "TO" number in "Twilio" trial version so that I can make sms / call to any of these numbers?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call

I am using twilio trial version, I have registered using my mobile number lets say 123456. So twilio has added this number as my caller ID or "TO" number and I can only send message / call to this number. Now I want to try another number as well, like 787878, but it is not letting me add this number as its mentioning that "only verified numbers" can be used as a "TO" number. So I decided to add this number here in screenshot
["TO" number image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLkuQ.png) (note: existing one is the number with which I made Twilio account)
but to verify, it is not sending me verification code on mobile via sms, is there any restriction that we can use only one number in trial account? Or can I use another phone number as a "TO" number as well? If it is so, then can I remove old number and then will I be able to add the new one?

Comment: Check the Twilio call logs. Maybe the SMS is being sent but being blocked by your phone company. You have to go through the 10dlc process to validate your phone numbers to send sms. This is to prevent spam.

Comment: You should be able to add multiple verified caller IDs. 
I know it's not a real answer to you problem but it would be an easy workaround: Have you tried upgrading the account or is something blocking you from doing this?

Comment: The sms / call doesn't send, infact it shows me error in as that "The number is unverified". Trial accounts may only make calls / sms to verified numbers. But when I try to add my number in Caller ID, it does not send me verification code, I tried multiple times

Comment: The "The number is unverified" is right if the number is not verified. I'm not sure why you don't receive the code but I'd recommend to upgrade the account.

Comment: I have exactly same problem: trial account with a phone number verified, created by another person. When I try to verify my phone number to make some tests I won't receive any code. I've tried activating 2F authentication with the same number and the verification code reaches inmediately but the code for adding a verified caller ID never happens to reach, so I think the problem is not on the phone number I'm using but on the SMS sending process by Twilio.